# WPF UserControl Triggers from parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl within a frame on it's parent window. In the usercontrol, I have a textbox that needs to be edited when a button on the parent window is toggled.

I'm trying to do it using triggers
UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxEdit" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EditButton}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="EditTextBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{StaticResource TextBoxEdit}"
        Text="Edit me" />
</Grid>
```

This works fine when there is a button named EditButton within the usercontrol, but is it possible to do this when the EditButton is within the parent window?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="EditButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">Edit</ToggleButton>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Source="Home.xaml" />
</Grid>
```

It is my understanding that the data context for the usercontrol will be inherited from the parent window, so is it possible to do it as simple as a trigger bound to the button or will I have to use a viewmodel/button commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but is it possible to do this when the EditButton is within the parent window?

No, it's not because then the `Button` and `TextBox` belong to different naming scopes.

> It is my understanding that the data context for the usercontrol will be inherited from the parent window, so is it possible to do it as simple as a trigger bound to the button or will I have to use a viewmodel/button commands?

You should bind the `IsChecked` property of the `ToogleButton` to a source property of a view model, and then bind the trigger to same source property:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
...
```

Make sure that the view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my question with my viewmodel, where do I go from here?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Please see the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615689/wpf-mainwindow-toggle-property-in-usercontrol-via-viewmodel Thanks.