# WPF MainWindow toggle property in UserControl via ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a UserControl within a frame on it's parent window. In the usercontrol, I have a textbox that needs to be edited when a button on the parent window is toggled.

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxEdit" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanEdit}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="EditTextBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{StaticResource TextBoxEdit}"
        Text="Edit me" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="EditButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding CanEdit}">Edit</ToggleButton>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Source="Home.xaml" />
</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool canEdit;
    public bool CanEdit
    {
        get { return canEdit; }
        set
        {
            canEdit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CanEdit");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

How do I get the data trigger to work properly? Is the best way to create another view model for the usercontrol and then communicate the values between the 2 viewmodels? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using a Frame?

Comment: I have one main window that has a navigation bar to change the content of the frame to different usercontrols, thought a frame was the best way to do this. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Is Home.xaml the UserControl?

Comment: Yes. Home.xaml is the usercontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the best way to create another view model for the usercontrol and then communicate the values between the 2 viewmodels?

The most common way would be for the `UserControl` to simply inherit the `DataContext` of the parent window so they both can bind to the same property.

This doesn't work out-of-the-box when you are using a `Frame` though.

You could either replace the `Frame` with a `ContentControl`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="EditButton" IsChecked="{Binding CanEdit}">Edit</ToggleButton>
<ContentControl>
    <local:Home />
</ContentControl>
```

Or you could handle the `DataContextChanged` event for the `Frame` and set the `DataContext` of its `Content` explicitly as suggested by @Joe White here: [page.DataContext not inherited from parent Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame)

Comment: This works exactly how I want it in my test project but I'm having some problems with my actual application, I think I need to rethink the structure of it. But your answer has helped a lot, so thank you.